# redirecting/merging gmail emails to google apps

Tags: g-suite, gmail

I have a google apps account and want to have access to my gmail emails through this account. Is there a way, I can merge the accounts or move the emails from gmail to google apps account as soon as they arrive?

Please suggest.

Comment: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/ is the right place for this question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could synchronize both mailboxes using [imapsync](http://www.linux-france.org/prj/imapsync/).

Either you do that regularly or you synchronize the mailboxes once and then setup a mail forwarding in your GMail account to your Google Apps account, see [Forwarding mail to another email account automatically](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=10957).

I'd go with the second option.